# Задача с acmp.ru, Python, Memory limit exceeded

Tags: python

Решаю задачу [396 "Точки и отрезки"](https://acmp.ru/index.asp?main=task&id_task=396). Формулировка:

> Дано N отрезков на числовой прямой и M точек на этой же прямой. Для
> каждой из данных точек определите, скольким отрезкам она принадлежит.
> Точка x считается принадлежащей отрезку с концами a и b, если
> выполняется двойное неравенство min(a, b) ≤ x ≤ max(a, b).
>
> **Входные данные** Первая строка входного файла INPUT.TXT содержит два целых числа N – число отрезков и M – число точек (1 ≤ N, M ≤ 105). В
> следующих N строках по два целых числа ai и bi – координаты концов
> соответствующего отрезка. В последней строке M целых чисел –
> координаты точек. Все числа во входном файле не превосходят по модулю
> 109.
>
> **Выходные данные** В выходной файл OUTPUT.TXT выведите M чисел – для каждой точки количество отрезков, в которых она содержится.
>
> (Ограничения 2 секунды, 16 Мб)

Вот мое решение на Питоне, получающее Memory limit exceeded на "большом" тесте.

```
fin = open("input.txt")
fout = open("output.txt","w")
n, m = map(int, fin.readline().split())
left_edges = {}
right_edges = {}
for i in range(n):
    a, b = map(int, fin.readline().split())
    if a > b:
        a, b = b, a
    try:
        left_edges[a] += 1
    except KeyError:
        left_edges[a] = 1
    try:
        right_edges[b] += 1
    except KeyError:
        right_edges[b] = 1
numbers = [int(x) for x in fin.readline().split()]
scan = sorted(set(left_edges) | set(right_edges) | set(numbers))
counter = 0
numb_dict = {}
for elem in scan:
    counter += left_edges.get(elem, 0)
    numb_dict[elem] = counter
    counter -= right_edges.get(elem, 0)
for numb in numbers:
    fout.write(str(numb_dict[numb]) + ' ')
fin.close()
fout.close()
```

Задача выглядит как типовая для использования сканирующей прямой - так и делаю.

Осложняет дело то, что исходные точки не отсортированы, поэтому при сканировании недостаточно проверять принадлежность "интересной" точки множеству numbers и сразу выводить соответствующее значение счетчика, приходится организовывать еще один цикл. В приведенном решении я делаю это через словарь, в первой версии пытался делать через введение нового списка длины m и постепенном его заполнении (вышло медленнее).

В итоге решение не влезает в лимит по памяти - вроде бы чуть-чуть. Вопрос - где можно сэкономить?

Вообще, ограничения для Питона очень жесткие: за все годы задачу сдали только [четыре человека](https://acmp.ru/index.asp?main=bstatus&id_t=396&lang=PY), из них трое на PyPy. В попытках решения почти все питонисты останавливаются на третьем тесте, первом "большом", где количество точек и отрезков набрано по максимуму. Мое его проходит, но стопорится на четвертом...

Первый вариант вывода через список был таким:

```
segment_numbers = [0] * m
for elem in scan:
    counter += left_edges.get(elem, 0)
    if elem in numbers:
        segment_numbers[numbers.index(elem)] = counter
    counter -= right_edges.get(elem, 0)
fout.write(' '.join(map(str, segment_numbers)))
```

и я понимаю, что он кривой: каждый раз вызывается индекс, как я понимаю, это затратная операция, но как это оптимизировать, не понимаю.

P.S. Пока писал, еще один вопрос образовался. Я обычно добавление элементов в словарь организовываю через try - except:

```
try:
    left_edges[a] += 1
except KeyError:
    left_edges[a] = 1
```

а не через if'ы:

```
if a in left_edges:
    left_edges[a] += 1
else:
    left_edges[a] = 1
```

Это как, нормальная практика или так лучше не делать?

Comment: Там уже пять решивших на Питоне. :)

Comment: try/except - очень затратная конструкция в любом языке программирования, поэтому любой другой способ обычно лучше.

Answer (score 1):

### Память и скорость

Максимальное потребление памяти:

- `left_edges` - *N*,
- `right_edges` - *N*,
- `numbers` - *M*,
- `set(left_edges)` - *N*,
- `set(right_edges)` - *N*,
- `set(numbers)` - *M*,
- `set(left_edges) | set(right_edges)` - *2N*,
- `set(left_edges) | set(right_edges) | set(numbers)` - *2N + M*,
- `scan` - *2N + M*.

В момент вычисления переменной `scan` всё вышеперечисленное в памяти одновременно. Сумма *10N + 4M*. Это очень много.

`numb_dict` требует `2N + M`. Используется только `M`.

Используется большое количество обращений к словарям и множествам. Решить можно без всего этого - одной сортировкой и массивами.

Ну не одной сортировкой, а несколькими. Код ниже проходит все тесты.

Основная идея - хранить все списки как [array.array](https://docs.python.org/3/library/array.html). В отличие от списков массивы хранят данные компактно, в нашем случае по четыре байта на элемент. Массив `lefts` - начала отрезков, массив `rights` - концы, `xs` - координаты точек, `indices` - индексы точек упорядоченные по их координатам, `levels` - количество отрезков покрывающих точку. Индексация `levels` и `xs` совпадает.

`array.array` не умеет сортироваться. Сортировки делаются через создание временных списков. Памяти на это хватает.

`xs` и `levels` можно было бы объединить. Это не сделано чтобы не запутывать код ещё больше.

Последний цикл - заметание по координатам точек. Перебираются индексы, но так что координаты не убывают.

В циклах `while` отличаются условия: одно нестрогое, второе строгое. Если вы понимаете почему так сделано, вы понимаете как устроено решение.

"Часовые" в массивах `lefts` и `rights` упрощают циклы `while`: не нужно следить за выходом индексов `li` и `ri` за пределы массивов.

```
import array


n, m = map(int, input().split())
lefts = array.array('i')
rights = array.array('i')
for _ in range(n):
    l, r = sorted(map(int, input().split()))
    lefts.append(l)
    rights.append(r)
    
lefts = array.array('i', sorted(lefts))
lefts.append(10 ** 9 + 1) # sentinel
rights = array.array('i', sorted(rights))
rights.append(10 ** 9 + 1) # sentinel

xs = array.array('i', map(int, input().split()))
indices = array.array('I', sorted(range(m), key=lambda i: xs[i]))

levels = array.array('I', range(m))
level = 0
li = 0
ri = 0
for i in indices:
    x = xs[i]
    while lefts[li] <= x:
        level += 1
        li += 1
    while rights[ri] < x:
        level -= 1
        ri += 1
    levels[i] = level

print(*levels)
```

### Заполнение словаря

`if` лучше чем `try/except`.

Есть ещё `setdefault` и `defaultdict` и `get`. Они ещё лучше.

**TODO: добавить примеры**

Comment: (Заполнение словаря) Так лучше или все равно коряво?  
`left_edges[a] = left_edges.get(a, 0) + 1  
 right_edges[b] = right_edges.get(b, 0) + 1`

Comment: `get` - хорошее решение.

Comment: `array.array` - класс, не знал, что так можно было - слышал только про NumPy, но его на acmp нельзя. Ваше решение в целом понятно: хорошо, когда есть "дешевые" массивы. Попытаюсь с этим новым знанием свое решение улучшить. Я успел заметить мелькнувшие gc.collect и enumerate ;)

Comment: `gc.collect` иногда помогает если строгие требования к памяти. В какой-то момент оно было нужно, потом я поменял и упростил код. `enumerate` тоже был нужен для "сложного" решения.